# How to transform this variable linearly?

Tags: functions

I'm working on a model. I have a variable, lets say "a". It can take the values 0,1,2,3,4. For my model I'm only interested in 1 and 0.

How can I linearly transform this into a expression, which results as 0 if a is 0, and results as 1 if a is 1,2,3 or 4.

I tried a+1 / a+1 which failed for zero, but worked fine for the rest. I worked hard on this but I cannot make progress. Non-linear answers also welcome, as they can provide inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

You are not transforming it linearly. One way to do what you want is

if $a \gt 0$, then 1, else 0

another way is

ceiling (a/5)

Answer (score 0):

You can write $[a \ne 0]$, using using [Iverson  Bracket Notation](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Iverson%27s_Convention).

Answer (score 0):

If we agree in $0^0=1$, then $1-0^a$ does the job.